# When does Common subexpression elimination apply?

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization, microbenchmark

```
for (Pair p : pairs) {
    double f = foo(p)
    ...
}
```

foo() performs a simple mathematical calculation as follows:

```
double foo(Pair p) {
    return Math.cos(p.x) + Math.sin(p.y);
}
```

If all the items in pairs are the same, can the Java compiler optimise this using Common subexpression elimination? Or is there another optimisation that occurs? I am asking since I have found a significant time reduction when more values in pairs are the same.

Comment: "I have found a significant time reduction" how did you measure that?

Comment: "when more values in pairs are the same" what are the "same" values? Is it possible that they are "simple" cases (e.g. zero) that are just quicker to calculate?

Comment: CSE refers to situations such as `a[i*3]=b[i*3] / c[i*3]`, where we can identify that all 3 occurrences of `i*3` will have the same value during any given evaluation of the whole expression, so the expression can be rewritten as `$t=i*3; a[$t] = b[$t] / c[$t];`

Comment: The normal compiler cannot do anything here because at compile time there are no common subexpressions since the values are generally unknown. Or are you talking about the jit?

Comment: First of all: the traditional Java *compiler* (i.e the one called `javac` that transforms .java files into .class files) does almost no optimizations and definitely none of the type you describe. These kind of optimizations are the area of the runtime (with the JIT compiler) in the Java world.

Comment: @AndyTurner I used JMH to benchmark by creating a random set of data and duplicating one randomly chosen value such that it takes up 0%,25%,50%,75% and finally 100% of the dataset and then benchmarked the time taken

Comment: I also tried randomising the foo() function which resulted in the performance changes due to changes in the percentage of identical values, being removed

Comment: Which suggests to me that the results were being cached

Comment: @JoachimSauer oh okay. Is there a name for this kind of optimisation by the JIT compiler?

Comment: Yes, the name is "common subexpression elimination".  The "subexpressions" in that case are results computed by the not-very-optimized bytecode in the .class files.  It won't apply here to values that only *happen* to be the same at runtime.  (In theory it could see how they're generated and do huge transformations of the loop logic to fold this processing into the code that stores identical values in the first place, but that's very unlikely, especially for a JIT because it needs to compile quickly, so it can't spend too much time looking for optimizations.)

Comment: Any discussion about benchmark results is pointless when you don’t post the benchmark code.